# Typescript: optional import of 'fs' package, browser vs nodejs

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a large TypeScript library.   Most of it is platform neutral, but there is a small feature which would benefit from files system access when running on Node.js.   All my testing is currently done on Node.js, and I know file access from a browser sandbox is blocked by design, so it's OK if the feature is not available on browsers.

I'd like to have a conditional import (or require), but I understand that doesn't work.  How can I work around this?

Is a JavaScript bundler tool a part of a solution, perhaps by returning null from any import attempt that fails?  Are any of the bundlers better at this than others?

Here's my current code:

```
    /**
     * Creates a {@link CodePointCharStream} given a string containing a
     * path to a file on disk and the encoding of the bytes
     * contained in the file.  If no encoding is specified, it defaults to 'utf-8'.
     *
     * Reads the entire contents of the file into the result before returning.
     *
     * For JavaScript this can only work on node.js.   Browsers can't read files.
     */
    export function fromFileName(fileName: string, encoding: string = "utf-8"): CodePointCharStream {
        if (typeof require !== "function") {
            throw new Error("File I/O not supported on this platform.");
        }
        const fs = require("fs");
        const path = require("path");
        fileName = path.resolve(fileName);
        const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fileName).toString(encoding);
        return fromString(fileContent, fileName);
    }
```

Comment: `import` statements must be statically resolved (i.e. top level) statements, but node `require` can be conditionally called, and in typescript you can mix the two.

Comment: I tried `const fs = require('fs')`, but typescript then complained about fs being of type any.

Comment: Did you install the node types? `npm install --save @types/node`

Comment: Yes, already done that.  If I use import syntax, it knows the type.

Comment: I'm now wondering if I have to use a triple-slash directive.

Comment: Maybe. You might also look at something like this https://github.com/jvilk/BrowserFS

Comment: Most bundling tools will recognize the dynamic [`import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Import) function and TypeScript should be able to correctly infer the type if you pass the string literal `fs`, but you'd need to convert `fromFileName()` to be an `async` function in order to dynamically import it.

Comment: Yes, use dynamic `import`, and let polyfills do the hard work for you.

Comment: As dynamic import requires async, it is not attractive.  I guess I'll  need some sort of conditional compilation  to omit the function on builds targeted to browsers